# Ruby index of array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Consider I have an array of integer elements. In which I am trying to find the index where a long sequence of repetitive numbers begins.

```
my_array = [100, 101, 100, 102, 100, 100, 101, 100, 250, 251, 253, 260, 250, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 120]
```

Bellow is the way I am trying to find the index. Can anyone suggest me more optimised and correct way of doing it?

```
my_array.each with_index do |e, x|
  match = e.to_s * 5
  next_10 = my_array[x + 1, 5].join()

  if match == next_10
    puts "index #{x}"
    break
  end
end

#index 14
```

Comment: What is your definition of array getting normalised?

Comment: @ray same elements starts appearing.

Comment: @Aparichith _"same elements starts appearing"_ is a bit vague. That almost sounds like "you'll know it when you see it". Be more specific, please.

Comment: @Stefan We can define function for finding starting index of longest repeating number sequence but it does not define it normalised.

Comment: _"Can anyone suggest me [a] more [...] correct way"_ – what's wrong with your approach?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Do you wish to find the index of the first element of the longest sequence of equal elements? If so, that needs to be made clear. Nowhere do you say you are looking for the *longest* sequence having a certain property. Feel free to use the content of my first sentence in an edit, if iI am correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_array.index.with_index{|value,index| my_array[index,6].uniq.size==1}
```

This is a kind of tweak, if you mean "optimised" just in the way code looks like.If you mean optimised performance. it does not fit.

Comment: can you elaborate how number 6 works here? seems it will not work for other combinations of integers.

Comment: The question has been changed. This answer is based on the demonstration code.

Answer (score 1):

In first iteration, I am getting array of repeating elements sequence and then I proceed further with logic,

```
groups = my_array[1..-1].inject([[my_array[0]]]) { |m, n| m.last[0] == n ? m.last << n : m << [n]; m }
# => [[100], [101], [100], [102], [100, 100], [101], [100], [250], [251], [253], [260], [250], [200], [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100], [120]]

groups[0,groups.index(groups.sort { |a,b| a.count <=> b.count }.last)].flatten.count
# => 14
```

Using regex, it can be precise and simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_array = [100, 101, 100, 102, 100, 100, 101, 100, 250, 251, 253, 260, 250, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 120]


index_and_repetitions = lambda { |my_array|
  stk = {}
  previous = my_array[0]
  last_index = 0
  stk[last_index] = 1
  my_array.drop(0).each_with_index{|item, index|
    if item == previous
      stk[last_index] += 1
    else
      last_index = index
      stk[last_index] = 1
      previous = item
    end
  }
  stk
}

stk = index_and_repetitions.call(my_array)
puts stk.key(stk.values.max)
```

you can find [benchmark results(compared to others answers)](https://gist.github.com/oshanz/08fc0dd643f2574fff1f7a96e7320860) from here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the objective is to find the index of the first element of the longest sequence of equal elements in the given array.

```
my_array = [100, 101, 100, 102, 100, 100, 101, 100, 250, 251, 253, 260, 250, 200,
            100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
            120]
```

Here that would be `14`, the index of `100` that is followed by 8 more `100`'s.

We can do that as follows.

```
my_array.each_index.chunk { |i| my_array[i] }.
         max_by { |_,a| a.size }.
         last.
         first
           #=> 14
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum0 = my_array.each_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [100, 101, 100,..., 100, 120]:each_index>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
  #    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Continuing,

```
enum1 = enum0.chunk { |i| my_array[i] }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x000058d8d09ec8a0>:each>
```

In view of the above expression's return value, `enum1` could be thought of as a *compound enumerator*, though Ruby has no such concept. Let's see the values `enum1` will generate.

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[100, [0]], [101, [1]], [100, [2]], [102, [3]], [100, [4, 5]],
  #    [101, [6]], [100, [7]], [250, [8]], [251, [9]], [253, [10]],
  #    [260, [11]], [250, [12]], [200, [13]],
  #    [100, [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]],
  #    [120, [23]]]
```

Continuing,

```
a = enum1.max_by { |v,a| a.size }
  #=> [100, [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]]
```

As `v` is not used in the block, this expression would customarily be written:

```
a = enum1.max_by { |_,a| a.size }
```

The presence of the underscore (a valid local variable) signals to the reader that that block variable is not used in the block calculation. The last two steps are as follows.

```
b = a.last
  #=> [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22] 
b.first
  #=> 14
```

See [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) and [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by).